# Is there a way to set-cookies from laravel to another domain after Ajax request?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cookies

I'm learning about Laravel passport package and creating a SPA using Vue.js to test it, I'm wondering about saving the Token in the client browser, If I saved it on local storage it would be accessible from Javascript and anyone run js on the browser would be able to read it !
My questions are; What is the solution for this situation ? 
If I saved the token in the cookies It would be accessible too, and I read about httpOnly cookies, so How can I set the cookies to save the token from the response from the API if it's not accessible by Javascript ?
Is there a way to save the cookies from the API ?

I hope I can find answers for my Questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of things to understand here.

#### HTTP only cookie

First, HTTP cookies are set by the server using **set-cookie** header. In this case, you as a developer need not do anything. The browser will automatically set it for you and will send back to the server on each Ajax or non-ajax requests. It will send the cookie as long as it is not expired.

#### LocalStorage

When using LocalStorage for storing the token, any JavaScript code can read it (known as XSS attack if misused). **But, the key thing to understand here is that other domain's JavaScript code cannot read the LocalStorage**. The scope is restricted to your own site. Other website's JS cannot read it. So, if you are not using any external dependency or compromised CDN, you are safe.

#### Cross-site cookie

No. It is impossible to set a cross-domain cookie under any circumstances. Only other domain's server can set a cookie for itself (Unless you have some backend mechanism like Gmail + Youtube to share session). However, in case of a subdomain, the following things are allowed:

- Parent domain can set a cookie for any child domain. That is `example.com` can set a cookie for `*.example.com`.
- Child domain can set a cookie for the parent domain. That is `xyz.example.com` can set a cookie for `example.com`.

Of course, the rules are more complicated than that. [This article](https://blog.webf.zone/ultimate-guide-to-http-cookies-2aa3e083dbae) should help you understand further.

Comment: Thank you for answering me but I think I didn't get enough, the application is SPA which means it's not important to be at the same Server, the client makes a request to the API which is the back-end and it should Generate a token and give it to the user for further requests, The Client should store this Token somewhere ! it's not safe to store it in Localstorage because most sites use CDN these days. which brings me to the situation I'm talking about, What's that safe place ? HTTP only cookies are the solution I think but how can I set these cookies while The back-end is just API

Comment: @MahmoudBenJabir, I understand your concern. When you have SPA type architecture and wish to use cookies, then you need UI-server or reverse proxy like middleware in between. Its job is to handle sessions and server SPA with history mode. Your SPA should not make a direct call to API server; Instead, it should make a call to reverse proxy which will then proxy the call to API server. By doing this, you get UI and API on the same domain and thus cookie solution works.

Comment: @MahmoudBenJabir, Alternately if you have UI domain and API domain as sibling domains then cookies set by API server would be picked by your application and HTTP only solution should work.